# Function in mixin not called in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I want when:

I click resend OTP, the otp is sent and timer start counting down...Currently, the OTP is sent but the countdown doesn't work when. Only works the first time I navigate to the screen

While using provider, I cant get the state to update from the view.

When I used bloc Consumer it worked but this does not work

I have a view which is supposed to resetTimer when OTP has been sent

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 verificationProvider = 
 context.watch<AuthVerificationProvider>();
 final state = verificationProvider.authVerificationState;
if (state is AuthVerificationResentOtpState) {
  resetTimer(); --> The timer doesn't count down when this is called
}
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  appBar: getAppBar(context, titleText: 'Verify Email'),
  body: Form(
  child: InkWell(
         onTap: () {
         if (isTimerExpired) {
         //resend token
        context.read<AuthVerificationProvider>().resendEmailToken();
         }
      },
)
```

This is the provider:

```
Future<void> resendEmailToken() async {
authVerificationResponse = ApiResult<Unit>.loading('Sending email token');
_authVerificationState = AuthVerificationResendingOtpState();
notifyListeners();
final failureOrSuccess =
await authRepository.resendEmailToken();
failureOrSuccess.fold(
      (failure) {
    authVerificationResponse = ApiResult<Unit>.error(failure.message);
    Snack.e(failure.message);
    notifyListeners();
  },
      (_) {
    authVerificationResponse = ApiResult<Unit>.success(null);
    _authVerificationState = AuthVerificationResentOtpState();

    if (authVerificationResponse.isSuccess) {
      Snack.s('OTP has been sent to your email');
      notifyListeners();
    }
    notifyListeners();
  },
 );
}
```

This is mixin used in the view

```
mixin OtpTimeoutMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on 
 State<T> {
int timeoutMinutes = 1;
int timeoutSeconds = 60;
Timer? timer;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
startTimer();
}

void startTimer() {
timer?.cancel();

timeoutMinutes--;
timer = Timer.periodic(1.seconds, (timer) {
  if (timeoutMinutes == 0 && timeoutSeconds == 0) {
    timer.cancel();
  } else {
    setState(() {
      timeoutSeconds--;
      if (timeoutSeconds == 0 && timeoutMinutes > 0) {
        timeoutSeconds = 60;
        timeoutMinutes--;
      }
    });
  }
 });
}

void resetTimer() {
timeoutSeconds = 60;
timeoutMinutes = 1;
startTimer();
}

@override
void dispose() {
timer?.cancel();
super.dispose();
}

bool get isTimerRunning => timeoutMinutes > 0 && 
timeoutSeconds > 0;

bool get isTimerExpired => timeoutMinutes == 0 && 
timeoutSeconds == 0;

String getCurrentOtpTimeoutCount() =>
  "OTP expires in ${timeoutMinutes.toString().padLeft(2, 
"0")}:${timeoutSeconds.toString().padLeft(2, "0")} mins";
}
```

Can someone point out what is wrong with the code.?